# Angular Grid ag-grid columnDefs Dynamically change

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, ag-grid

I have a problem about `columnDefs` change dynamically. Here is my gridOptions:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [],
  enableFilter: true,
  rowData: null,
  rowSelection: 'multiple',
  rowDeselection: true
};
```

And when I retrieve data from server:

```
$scope.customColumns = [];

$http.post('/Home/GetProducts', { tableName: 'TABLE_PRODUCT' }).success(function (data) {
    angular.forEach(data.Columns, function (c) {
        $scope.customColumns.push(
            {
                headerName: c.Name,
                field: c.Value,
                width: c.Width
            }
        );
    });

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.customColumns;

    $scope.gridOptions.rowData = data.Products;
    $scope.gridOptions.api.onNewRows();
}).error(function () {

});
```

**Note: here c is column object which comes from server.**

When dynamically generating columns and assigning it to $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs there is blank grid but `$scope.customColumns` array is filled with right generated column objects. Please help me is this bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Pls help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018177/ag-grid-community-infinite-row-model-for-server-side-pagination-community-free/65040658#65040658

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In ag-grid the columns in gridOptions are used once at grid initialisation. If you change the columns after initialisation, you must tell the grid. This is done by calling `gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs()`

Details of this api method are provided in the [ag-grid documentation here](http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-api/index.php).

Comment: To be honest, this is very un-angular, un-react part of the design of ag-grid.

Comment: How can we get `columnDefs` after `setColumnDefs` by using ag-grid api without store it by myself? I tried with `gridOptions.api.getColumnDef()` but failed.

Comment: @aviit late to the party but: you have to keep track of column changes and additions yourself, there is no equivalent api.getColumnDefs() and won't be for a while if ever: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2038 I've submitted a feature request for something like api.getColumnDefs() but who knows when that will make it onto their development pipeline.

Comment: pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018177/ag-grid-community-infinite-row-model-for-server-side-pagination-community-free/65040658#65040658

Answer (score 5):

I think this has been fixed already.

I am able to do something like this now with latest angular and ag-grid. Please note I am using ngxs here, however this still indicates the ability to get the column definitions async as I am getting the column defs based on the property names of the data that is being returned from the back-end in this case rowData.

Firstly, I am fetching the row data from the back-end API.
Then when it is fetched I perform operations in the Select for column that map the headers from returned data to properties.

The data will not be displayed without headers, as soon as the headers are there it will redraw the grid with all the column definitions and data.

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData$ | async" 
    [columnDefs]="columnsDefs$ | async"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>


export class AgGridComponent {
    @Select(MyState.getColumnDefs) public columnsDefs$!: Observable<ReadonlyArray<any>>;

    @Select(MyState.getRowData) public rowData$!: Observable<ReadonlyArray<any>>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Angular**.
[See demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-updating-coldefs).

See the code below and note that the `ag-grid-angular` component has its columnDefs bound to a property in our component of the same name.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
```

Any updates to the columnDefs property in `app.component` will be reflected on our ag-Grid instance. For example, see how we set the initial column definitions in the `app.component`'s constructor function:

```
constructor() {
    this.columnDefs = colDefsAthleteExcluded;
}
```

We can add or remove columns in our ag-Grid instance, simply by updating the columnDefs bound property, passing in a new set of column definitions.

- Columns that didn't exist previously will be added to the ag-Grid instance.
- Columns that are not included in the new set will be removed from the ag-Grid instance.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Include Athlete Column" and "Exclude Athlete Column" buttons:

```
// removes the athlete column
onBtExcludeAthleteColumn() {
    this.columnDefs = colDefsAthleteExcluded;
}

// adds the athlete column
onBtIncludeAthleteColumn() {
    this.columnDefs = colDefsAthleteIncluded;
}
```

To update existing column definitions, we first call the ag-Grid API method `getColumnDefs()` to get a reference to the grid's current columns. We then map over the columns, changing any desired properties before updating our columnDefs bound property.

ag-Grid will then match existing columns with those in our ag-Grid instance and update the columns that have changed.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Set HeaderNames" and "Remove HeaderNames" buttons:

```
// sets each columns headerName property
setHeaderNames() {
    var columnDefs = this.gridApi.getColumnDefs();
    columnDefs.forEach(function(colDef, index) {
        colDef.headerName = "C" + index;
    });
    this.columnDefs = columnDefs;
}


// clears each columns headerName property
removeHeaderNames() {
    var columnDefs = this.gridApi.getColumnDefs();
    columnDefs.forEach(function(colDef, index) {
        colDef.headerName = undefined;
    });
    this.columnDefs = columnDefs;
}
```

**React**.
[See demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-updating-coldefs).

When using React we have the option of declaring ag-Grid columns declaratively. In the example above you'll see that we're creating ag-Grid Columns by mapping over a state variable `columns` and returning a `agGridColumn` React component for each column definition, spreading props while doing so:

```
const App = () => {
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(colDefsAthleteExcluded);

    return (
        {columns.map(column => (
            <AgGridColumn {...column} key={column.field} />
        ))}
```

To add or remove columns, we simply have to call the `setColumns` setState method, passing in a new set of column definitions.

- Columns that didn't exist previously will be added to the ag-Grid instance.
- Columns that are not included in the new set will be removed from the ag-Grid instance.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Include Athlete Column" and "Exclude Athlete Column" buttons:

```
// removes the athlete column
const onBtExcludeAthleteColumn = () => {
    setColumns(colDefsAthleteExcluded);
};

// adds the athlete column
const onBtIncludeAthleteColumn = () => {
    setColumns(colDefsAthleteIncluded);
};
```

To update existing column definitions, we first call the ag-Grid API method `getColumnDefs()` to get a reference to the grid's current columns. We then map over the columns, changing any desired properties before calling `setColumns` and updating our `columns` state variable.

ag-Grid will then match existing columns with those in our ag-Grid instance and update the columns that have changed.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Set HeaderNames" and "Remove HeaderNames" buttons:

```
// sets each columns headerName property
const setHeaderNames = () => {
    const newColumns = gridApi.getColumnDefs();
    newColumns.forEach((newColumn, index) => {
        newColumn.headerName = "C" + index;
    });
    setColumns(newColumns);
};

// clears each columns headerName property
const removeHeaderNames = () => {
    const newColumns = gridApi.getColumnDefs();
    newColumns.forEach((newColumn, index) => {
        newColumn.headerName = undefined;
    });
    setColumns(newColumns);
};
```

**Vue**.
[See demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-updating-coldefs).

Below you'll see that our `ag-grid-vue` component has its columnDefs bound to a property in our component of the same name.

```
<ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    id="myGrid"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
```

Any updates to the `columnDefs` property in Vue component will be reflected in our ag-Grid instance. For example, see how we set the initial column definitions in the `beforeMount` lifecycle method:

```
beforeMount() { 
    this.columnDefs = colDefsAthleteExcluded;
}
```

To add or remove columns to our ag-Grid instance, we update the `columnDefs` bound property, passing in a new set of column definitions.

- Columns that didn't exist previously will be added to the ag-Grid instance.
- Columns that are not included in the new set will be removed from the ag-Grid instance.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Include Athlete Column" and "Exclude Athlete Column" buttons:

```
// removes the athlete column
btnExcludeAthleteColumn() {
    this.columnDefs = colDefsAthleteExcluded;
},  
// adds the athlete column
btnIncludeAthleteColumn() {
    this.columnDefs = colDefsAthleteIncluded;
}
```

To update existing column definitions, we first call the ag-Grid API method `getColumnDefs()` to get a reference to the grid's current columns. We then map over the columns, changing any desired properties before updating our `columnDefs` bound property.

ag-Grid will then match existing columns with those in our ag-Grid instance and update the columns that have changed.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Set HeaderNames" and "Remove HeaderNames" buttons:

```
// sets each columns headerName property
setHeaderNames() {
    var columnDefs = this.gridApi.getColumnDefs();
    columnDefs.forEach(function(colDef, index) {
        colDef.headerName = "C" + index;
    });
    this.columnDefs = columnDefs;
}


// clears each columns headerName property
removeHeaderNames() {
    var columnDefs = this.gridApi.getColumnDefs();
    columnDefs.forEach(function(colDef, index) {
        colDef.headerName = undefined;
    });
    this.columnDefs = columnDefs;
}
```

**Vanilla JS**.
[See demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-updating-coldefs).

When using vanilla JS, column definitions cannot be bound to a property within our application as JavaScript does not have a built-in mechanism for reactive data. Instead we use the ag-Grid API method `setColumnDefs()` to set and update our columns.

To add or remove columns to our ag-Grid instance, we call the `setColumnDefs` API, passing in a new set of column definitions.

- Columns that didn't exist previously will be added to the ag-Grid instance.
- Columns that are not included in the new set will be removed from the ag-Grid instance.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Include Athlete Column" and "Exclude Athlete Column" buttons:

```
// removes athlete column
function onBtExcludeAthleteColumn() {
    gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(colDefsAthleteExcluded);
}

// adds athlete column
function onBtIncludeAthleteColumn() {
    gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(colDefsAthleteIncluded);
}
```

To update existing column definitions, we first call the ag-Grid API method `getColumnDefs()` to get a reference to the grid's current columns. We then map over the columns, changing any desired properties before calling `setColumnDefs(colDefs)` and passing in the updated columns.

ag-Grid will then match existing columns with those in our ag-Grid instance and update the columns that have changed.

Please see the code for this below in the event handlers for the "Set HeaderNames" and "Remove HeaderNames" buttons:

```
// sets each columns headerName property
function setHeaderNames() {
    var columnDefs = gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs();
    columnDefs.forEach(function(colDef, index) {
        colDef.headerName = "C" + index;
    });
gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
}

// clears each columns headerName property
function removeHeaderNames() {
    var columnDefs = gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs();
    columnDefs.forEach(function(colDef, index) {
        colDef.headerName = undefined;
    });
    gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
}
```

Read the full blog post on our [website](https://blog.ag-grid.com/binding-and-updating-column-definitions-in-ag-grid/) or check out our [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/) for a great variety of scenarios you can implement with ag-Grid.

Ahmed Gadir | Developer @ ag-Grid

Comment: Hey @ahmedg94 this doesn't seem to work in React? I understand the concept, use setState / useState to cause a re-render, but in my example, it not re-rendering. I'm using  the enterprise treeData along w/ custom cellrenderers so it's a little complicated

Comment: Figured it out. I guess we still have to call `gridApi.setColumnDefs(colDefs)` ?  I don't see it in your write up

Comment: This is the longest answer I've ever seen on SO. Probably would be a good idea to extract it into a blog. Cheers.