# Need to update cellEditor Params dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Need to pass value to cellEditorParams after user double clicks on grid row. Application calls service on row click and the response has to be pass to cellEditorParams?

Comment: Could you please explain more? or put some code in plunker? It's very hard to know exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is setting some variables inside the `state` and using those as `cellEditorParams` when user double clicks you can use `setState` inside `onRowDoubleClick` to change the variables value to whatever you want. Hope this might help.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem of the question here, so I need to pass a variable (that is the result of a REST call) to  cellEditorParams, can you please go more in detail with your answer? or reply to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535862/how-to-init-celleditor-dynamically-with-the-result-of-a-rest-call

Answer (score 0):

In ag-grid the columns in gridOptions are used once at grid initialisation. If you change the columns after initialisation, you must tell the grid. This is done by calling gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs()

Details of this api method are provided in the  ag-grid documentation here
http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-api/index.php

[Angular Grid ag-grid columnDefs Dynamically change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743534/angular-grid-ag-grid-columndefs-dynamically-change/31816050#31816050)