# ag-grid + AngularJS dynamically load new table failed

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743534/angular-grid-ag-grid-columndefs-dynamically-change), I tried to call `api.setColumnDefs` and `api.setRowData` to dynamically load new table definition with new corresponding data, and it failed.

I guess it comes from that the plugin tries to refresh GUI after `api.setColumnDefs` but before `api.setRowData`. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Px3a4NwtRb631yaVvAtU?p=preview) is the code at Plunker (it is based on [Advanced AngularJS 1.x Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/)),.

Please review and help: what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by calling `api.setRowData();` to clear all data before calling `api.setColumnDefs` to reset column-defintions.