# How can i create this table in ag-grid? Is it possible?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm new to ag-grid and want to create this(attached below) table where the columns are added dynamically in ag-grid. Any solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndSp2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by generation ag-grid colDef on the fly.
For example check this link: https://embed.plnkr.co/0s1oSe/

Also similar problem was discussed here [Angular Grid ag-grid columnDefs Dynamically change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743534/angular-grid-ag-grid-columndefs-dynamically-change)